# G-streamer, what is it?

Tags: sound, gstreamer

G-streamer, what is it?

How can I determine if it is already installed?

I've already looked in the obvious places - where and how do I get it?

Answer (score 8):

> GStreamer is a streaming media framework that enables applications to
>   share a common set of plugins for things like video decoding and
>   encoding, audio encoding and decoding, audio and video filters, audio
>   visualisation, Web streaming and anything else that streams in
>   real-time or otherwise.<sup>[Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/multimedia/gstreamer.html)</sup>

To see if you have it,  just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
gst-inspect-1.0 fakesrc
```

If not, do this for Ubuntu 13.10, and older

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gstreamer-developers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0*
```

and for 14.04

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ddalex/gstreamer 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0*
```

Or visit [Here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/multimedia/gstreamer.html)

Comment: Are the PPAs needed?

Comment: I've got gstreamer available without a ppa in 14.04 and 14.10